# Scikit-Learn: Why am I Getting ValueError: Unknown label type while trying to fit breast cancer data set in SGDClassifier?

Tags: python, arrays, scikit-learn

This is my code :

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
breast_cancer = load_breast_cancer(as_frame = True)
breast_df = pd.DataFrame(breast_cancer["data"])
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
np.random.seed(42)
X = breast_df.drop("worst fractal dimension" ,axis=1)
y = breast_df["worst fractal dimension"]
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 0.2)
model = SGDClassifier()
model.fit(X_train,y_train)
model.score(X_test, y_test)
```

I'm trying to fit breast cancer data set in `SGDClassifier` but why do I get `ValueError: Unknown label type` ?

Comment: `SGDClassifier` is a classifier so you would need to either convert the target column "worst fractal dimension" to binary labels or change the model.

Comment: you used SGDClassifier, you would like to predict breast_df["worst fractal dimension"], however it is not class column.